# Are questions about using Wolfram Alpha to perform symbolic manipulation on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Recently, one of our users asked https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/solving-system-of-equations-with-wolfram-alpha, which is exactly what it says: how to solve a system of equations with Wolfram Alpha.

Despite looking an awful lot like a Mathematica question (from someone not in the Mathematica community, anyway), Mathematica.SE isn't interested, [as you can see on their Meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/are-questions-about-doing-symbolic-math-in-wolfram-alpha-on-topic-here/267#267).

In particular, I was struck by the following quote:

> This site is for users of Mathematica (mma), not Wolfram|Alpha (W|A) and so any question that does not involve the former is out of this site's scope. I know that W|A runs on mma and it kinda sorta understands mma syntax. However, opening the door to such questions will only lower the bar and result in hit-and-run questions from folks who just want a quick result from W|A.

The quote made me think: if we're going to get a bunch of questions from people who want a quick result from Wolfram Alpha, then I think those questions bring down the quality of the questions on the site and do our users a disservice.

What do you guys think? Are questions about using Wolfram Alpha to perform symbolic manipulation on topic here? If yes, I'm looking for a compelling counterargument that explains why people aren't going to ask multiple questions of the type "How do I use Wolfram Alpha to (insert type of symbolic manipulation)?", and I'm also looking for guidelines on what we should and should not accept when it comes to Wolfram Alpha questions.

Comment: In my mind it is outside the scope of the site, but I am pretty new here. I realize that I was the one that initially engaged on this question, but primarily that's because I thought it was a formulation issue.

Comment: @JeremyKozdon: I don't think engaging was a problem. Your answer was helpful. It's more the type of question being asked that concerns me.